# Checking if strings are equal in java using ==

Tags: java, string, equality

when i execute the code below, the output is "false"

```
String string1 = new String("ABC");  
String string2= new String("ABC");  
System.out.println(string1==string2);
```

However the output when I don't use the string class's constructor is "true"

```
String string1;
String string2;
string1="ABC";
string2= "ABC";
System.out.println(string1==string2);
```

I get that its better to use the .equals() methods but why the difference in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use equals since `==` doesn't always work. Even though objects are the same in memory it may be stored in different places, and `==` checks for objects identity and not equality.